# Steppers grinding when homing Marlin

Tags: marlin, diy-3d-printer, stepper, homing

When homing the 3D printer or running `G29`, the X & Y axes are grinding and not moving fully to the correct position. When I run the following G-code the print moves to the correct position with no issue `G0 X300.0 Y700.0 F7000` I was trying to debug the issue as I thought it had something to do with the homing and probing feed rate but after running `G0 F7000` I think that is not the issue.

This is a custom printer I have built myself, any help would be appreciated.

Video:

1st move is `G0 X190.0 Y331.0 F9000`

2nd move is homing to the centre of the bed

- Firmware: Marlin 2.1
- Printer Type: Cartesian

Comment: Please create a video demonstrating the issue and link it in the question, it is hard to gasp what is exactly meant by grinding and what is actually occurring. It sounds like it isn't a problem with the steppers, but could well be related to your design.

Comment: @0scar I've added a video

Comment: Are you hinting to the noise at the end of the video?

Comment: @0scar Yes,

1st Moving was G0 X190.0 Y331.0 F9000
2nd Move was homing in the centre of bed

Comment: Are the steppers getting enough current? Did you adjust the Vref or set a correct amperage for the stepper driver? It looks as if you ask too much from them for the current current settings.

Comment: @0scar I downgraded to Marlin Version 2.0 and that fixed the issue, so it looks like its something in the firmware the stepper drivers are getting enough current

Comment: Please write a proper answer how you fixed this and describe both versions in the answer. You can accept the answer after 48 hours. Thnaks for sharing!

Comment: @0scar It's not really fixing the issue as the problem is with Marlin 2.1 as the issue is present and i really want to get it fixed in that version

Comment: Have you "diffed" both the configuration files?